# Cross domain Ajax requests with Symfony2 (example with FOSUserBundle)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, cross-domain

I have a domain A "xbo.dev" and a sub domain B "blog.xbo.dev".

For example, on B domain, I would like to make an Ajax request to a domain A function.

I'm trying this with FOSUserBundle authentication. What I do :

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      if ('withCredentials' in xhr) {
          xhr.open('POST', 'http://xbo.dev/ajax/check_login_ajax', true);
          // I am using hard coding for the URL because with Routing.generate I would have this URL : http://blog.xbo.dev/ajax/check_login_ajax
          // which is not good because the request is on a different domain
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
                  console.log(xhr);
                  console.log('ok');
              } else {
                  console.log('ko');
              }
          }
      };
      xhr.send(encodeURI('_username=' + $('#co_'+varName+'username').val() + '&_password=' + $('#co_'+varName+'password').val() + '&_remember_me=' + false + '&_csrf_token=' + $('#co__csrf_token').val()));
```

I have a "ok" displayed by my request but nothing special is happening (I should have something like "Bad credentials" or "success" (or others), returned by FOSUserBundle check_login_ajax function, but no one of those is displayed...)

How can I do ?

EDIT 1 : Here is the result I have each time, either the login / password are correct or not

[image: Here is the Ajax result]

And with a normal $.ajax, I have this :

[image: Here is the Ajax result]

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement something to [relax the same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Relaxing_the_same-origin_policy) such as [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

As to your in-code note about hard-coding vs using the router to generate URLs, Symfony's router [supports hostnames](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

Comment: Thank you for the "Symfony's router supports hostnames". It can be very useful. I already read million things about CORS but the thing is that every method is different, and no one works for me. So, that's why I'm asking here how to do that in an easy way (using native javascript or jquery).

Comment: You have to do *something* to relax the same-origin policy - CORS is just one option.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. But can you give me one working solution with CORS for Symfony2 ?

Comment: I think you should probably ask that as a separate question